# Combining values of a specific column from consecutive rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am exporting my logs to SQL. The problem is that the logging API trims the Message column if it's length exceeds 800 chars and makes new entries with the rest of the message. I use logparser to export this data directly into SQL. So, for the rest of the discussing, let's assume I have to solve this problem in SQL.

This is what the SQL table looks like

```
ID    Timestamp    EventID   Message 
1     2014-04-23    abcd   "Some message"
```

If number of characters in Message is more than 800, we would have a new row in the table with the Message starting with "..." The original row would end with "..." to signify there is more to come.

For example

```
ID     Timestamp    EventID   Message 
1       2014-04-23    abcd   "Some message..."
2       2014-04-23    abcd   "...More message..."
3       2014-04-23    abcd   "...Even More message"
```

Notice that ID's of messages that belong together are consecutive. Nothing else is guaranteed. Timestamps are guaranteed to be same for a split but not distinct meaning there can be other entries in the table with the same timestamp. Same goes for `eventID`.

**Problem** 
Given this data in a table, I want to create a view which stitches together messages like these into a single unified message. So the users never have to know of the trimming that happened behind the scenes.

**Result should look like this**

```
ID    Timestamp    EventID   Message 
1     2014-04-23    abcd   "Some message More message even more message"
```

Comment: What if a message legitimately contains the string '...' ?

Comment: If we have a message that ends with "..." then an additional "..." would be placed by the logging API. And the same would go to SQL. This is only when the message was more than 800 chars and chars at 798, 799 and 800 happen to be '.'

Comment: It looks like you're looking for TSQL String aggregation. Take a look if this helps: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/06/25/t-sql-string-aggregate-in-sql-server/

Comment: That looks cool, but my problem is that timestamps are not distinct. Some other log message from another source can potentially have the same timestamp. All I can guarantee is consecutive ID's for messages which belong together.

Comment: After reading your comments I will suggest you to look into your schema, it requires serious attention. Your statement `All I can guarantee is consecutive ID's` but sql server doesnt guarantee this by its very nature, The order of the rows is irelavent in sql server unless you have a value(Column) that uniqely identifies each set of rows referencing to one message there is no way you can guarantee that when you pull data sql server will take into consideration the order of rows based on some sequence.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check the column length of the 'Message' column in your table.

In my opinion you can achieve this in either of the two options.

**Option 1:**
Run a sql script everyday that would create a single entry by combining all the messages in the 'Message' column for a certain Timestamp & EventID.

(I am assuming SQL Server but I am sure there's something equivalent in other RDBMS)

```
select Timestamp,EventID,
  CombinedMessage((SELECT Message + ' '
       FROM table t2
       where t2.Timestamp = t1.Timestamp
           and t2.EventID = t1.EventID
       FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
from table t1
into [NewTable]
group by Timestamp,EventIDenter code here
```

Yes, I am suggesting to create a new table that would contain your desired data.
This sql script could be called using a windows shell script or batch script (depending on your environment) which can then be scheduled using Windows Scheduler.

**Option 2:**
At my work place, I wrote an app in C# that would load the web logs into a database table every night using log parser and then perform our project specific post processing on the data that was imported into the table. So similarly, after importing your data into the table, you could create a simple console app that would do something as follows:

Use the following query to create a data set,

```
SELECT t.Timestamp, t.EventID, t.Message, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.EventID ORDER BY t.Timestamp) rownumber
FROM theTable t
```

Now in your app,

```
For Each rowNumber in  [data set]
{
  1. concatenate Message
  2. Insert into your original table the combined message record
  3. Calculate the MAX(LEN(Message)) and delete all other entries 
     whose message is less than MAX(LEN(Message)).
     You are now left with only one entry for a certain Timestamp, EventID & Message
}
```

Hope the above provided information helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT,[Timestamp] DATE,EventID VARCHAR(20),[Message] VARCHAR(800))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1,       '2014-04-23',    'abcd',   'Some message...'),
(2,       '2014-04-23',    'abcd',   '...More message...'),
(3,       '2014-04-23',    'abcd',   '...Even More message'),
(1,       '2014-04-23',    'abcE',   'Some other message...'),
(2,       '2014-04-23',    'abcE',   '...other More message...'),
(3,       '2014-04-23',    'abcE',   '...other Even More message')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t.EventID
      ,t.[Timestamp]
      ,REPLACE(STUFF((
            SELECT '  ' + [Message] 
            FROM @TABLE
            WHERE EventID = t.EventID
            ORDER BY ID ASC
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,''), '...', '') AS [Message]

FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.EventID ,t.[Timestamp]
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ EventID ║ Timestamp  ║                           Message                            ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ abcd    ║ 2014-04-23 ║ Some message More message Even More message                  ║
║ abcE    ║ 2014-04-23 ║ Some other message other More message other Even More message║
╚═════════╩════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: This looks cool. But it does not handle the case when the message is just a simple message (less than 800 chars). Also, this is combining all event ID's into a single message which is not what I want. Imagine there are entries with eventID "abcd" elsewhere in the table. It will concatenate those messages too.

Comment: After reading your comments I will suggest you to look into your schema, it requires serious attention. Your statement `All I can guarantee is consecutive ID's` but sql server doesnt guarantee this by its very nature, The order of the rows is irelavent in sql server unless you have a value(Column) that uniqely identifies each set of rows referencing to one message there is no way you can guarantee that when you pull data sql server will take into consideration the order of rows based on some sequence.